# What is wrong with my executable compiled with GCC?

Tags: gcc

This is my source file, base.c ...

```
#include "/usr/include/stdio.h"
int main( int   argc, char *argv[] )
{
    sprintf("%s\n", "woohoo");
    return(0);
}
```

I compile and execute with ...

```
jim@Pappy:~$ gcc base.c
jim@Pappy:~$ a.out
a.out: command not found
jim@Pappy:~$ ll a.out
-rwxrwxr-x 1 jim jim 7255 Jan 15 14:21 a.out*
```

So why is a.out not found?

Answer (score 1):

The executable is not found **because the directory it is in is not on your executable search path** `$PATH`.To run it directly, you need to prepend either a relative path

```
./a.out
```

or an absolute path

```
/home/jim/a.out
```

Comment: thanks.   I was under the impression that dot was always first in the path.  Sorry to waste your time.